# Set the gravity of an android xml drawable after rotating it

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable

How can I set the gravity of this drawable after the rotation?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate android:fromDegrees="45"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <bitmap
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/png_picture" />
</rotate>
```